# Best practice for system design checking a calculation results in JSON

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, system-design, anomaly-detection

I have a program that reads a JSON file, calculates, and outputs a JSON file on S3.

My question is how I should systematically check the output calculation seems okay?

I understand writing a unit test is a way I should do, but it doesn’t guarantee that the output file is safe. I’m thinking of making another program running on lambda that checks the output JSON.

For example, let’s say the program is calculating dynamic pricing in an area where has upper-bound value. Then I want to make sure all the calculation results in the JSON file don’t exceed the upper bound value or at least I’d like to monitor they are all safe or there are some anomalies.

I want to build an efficient and robust anomaly detection system so I don’t want to build the anomaly check in the same program to avoid single-point failures. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a second lambda function with the S3 trigger to fire when the JSON file is written into S3 from the original function.

In this 2nd lambda, you can verify the data and if there is anomaly, you may trigger an SNS or EventBridge event which can be used to log/inform/alert about the issue or may be to trigger a separate process to auto-correct anomalies.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Design by Contracts](https://wiki.c2.com/?DesignByContract) aka Contract Oriented Programming. Aka preconditions and postconditions.
If the output shall never exceed a certain value, then that is a postcondition of the code producing this value. The program should assert its postconditions.

If some other code relies on a value being bounded, then that is a precondition of that code. The code should assert this precondition. This is a type of [Defensive Programming](https://wiki.c2.com/?DefensiveProgramming) technique.